# Column "hylValue" does not belong to table

Tags: asp.net

I am getting exception **'dr["hylValue"]' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentException'**. What can be the possible way to get hylValue and hylName in ItemDataBound event.

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string hylValue = "https://www.google.co.in/";
        string hylName = "Google";
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["hylValue"] = hylValue.Split(new string[] {"~#~"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
        dr["hylName"] = hylName.Split(new string[] {"~#~"},StringSplitOptions.None);
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        Repeater1.DataSource = dt;
        Repeater1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
        {
            DataTable tbl = (DataTable)e.Item.DataItem;
            HyperLink hylFileUpload1 = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("HyperLink1");
            hylFileUpload1.Text = tbl.Rows[0]["hylValue"].ToString();
            hylFileUpload1.NavigateUrl = tbl.Rows[0]["hylName"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my **aspx code**

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <a href="mailto:Sumit.Patil@ABC.com" target="_blank">Sumit Patil</a>
    <br /><br />
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, your DataTable does not have any columns, but you're trying to access columns `hylValue` and `hylName`. Before accessing them, add them to your table, like this:

```
        string hylValue = "https://www.google.co.in/";
        string hylName = "Google";
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("hylValue", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("hylName", typeof(string));
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
```

Second, in `ItemDataBound`, `DataItem` is not `DataTable`, but `DataRowView`, so your code should look something like this:

```
 if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
        {
            DataRowView tbl = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
            HyperLink hylFileUpload1 = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("HyperLink1");
            hylFileUpload1.Text = tbl["hylValue"].ToString();
            hylFileUpload1.NavigateUrl = tbl["hylName"].ToString();
        }
```